# How to use document.querySelector and require with node.js and SQLite3

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

So pretty much I am trying to create an application that interacts with a database but cannot seem to get either one to work. Either the `require` causes an issue or the document keyword does (dependant on which I start from) I was just wondering if anyone knew a fix to this? I was trying to use classes and methods so I could split up the files as well but just doesnt want to work

I am very open to using another library or framework if need be so if you have any recommendations please let me know.

Here is my `main.js`

```
'use strict'

const handleSQLite = require('./handleSQLite.js')

let db = new handleSQLite();

db.openDatabase();



document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.search-sec').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.insert').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.remove').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.btns').classList.add('bts-search-clicked');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFB3E9";
    //document.querySelector('.insert').classList.add('.search-clicked');
    //document.querySelector('.insert').style.position = 'absolute';
    //document.querySelector('.insert').style.bottom = '-500px';
    console.log('search clicked');
});

document.querySelector('.insert').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.insert-sec').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.search').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.remove').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.btns').classList.add('bts-insert-clicked');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#BAE1C4";
    console.log('insert clicked');
});

// Remove Button Controller
document.querySelector('.remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //document.querySelector('.insert-sec').classList.remove('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.search').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.insert').classList.add('hidden');
    document.querySelector('.btns').classList.add('bts-remove-clicked');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#BAE1FF";
    console.log('remove clicked');
});
```

Here is my `server.js`

```
const http = require('http');
//const path = require("path");
//const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8080;
//const app = new express();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'./public'));



// Open Server
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    
    // Handle main page request
    if (req.url === '/'){
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write('Error: File Not Found');
            } else {    
                res.write(data);
            }
            res.end();
        })
    }

    // Handle stylesheet request
    else if (req.url === '/style.css') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css'})
        fs.readFile('style.css', function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write('Error: File Not Found');
          } else {
              res.write(data);
          }
          res.end();
        })
    }

    // Handle Javascript request
    else if (req.url === '/main.js') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'})
          fs.readFile('main.js', function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.write('Error: File Not Found');
              } else {
                  res.write(data);
              }
              res.end();
        })
    }

    // Handle image request
    else if (req.url === '/img/search.png') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
          fs.readFile('img/search.png', function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.write('Error: File Not Found');
              } else {
                  res.write(data);
              }
              res.end();
        })
    }

    // Handle SQL request
    else if (req.url === '/handleSQLite.js') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'})
          fs.readFile('handleSQLite.js', function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.write('Error: File Not Found');
              } else {
                  res.write(data);
              }
              res.end();
        })
    }

    // Handle database request
    else if (req.url === './db/storage.db') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
          fs.readFile('./db/storage.db', function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.write('Error: File Not Found');
              } else {
                  res.write(data);
              }
              res.end();
        })
    }


    
});


// Open the port to listen to
server.listen(port, '172.16.1.80' || 'localhost', function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);
    }
});
```

And here is my `handleSQLite.js` I know this one is very messy, I have just been trying tons of things

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

/*
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');
*/

class handleSQLite {
    constructor() {
        this.db;
    }


    openDatabase() {
        this.db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/storage.db', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Connected to the in memory SQlite database.')
            }
        });
    }

    closeDatabase() {
        this.db.close((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log('Close the database connection.');
          });
    }
    
}

/*
const data = new handleSQLite();

data.openDatabase();

data.closeDatabase();
*/








/*
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/storage.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the in memory SQlite database.')
    }
});
*/

let sqlItemSearchSuggest = `SELECT ItemName itemName
                            FROM   storage`

let sqlCreate = `CREATE TABLE storage(BoxNum REAL, ItemName TEXT, Location TEXT)`

let sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO storage VALUES(1, 'waffle maker', 'Storage Room')"


const searchSearchItems = async searchText => {
    const searchRes = await database.db.each(`SELECT ItemName FROM storage`, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }).toArray();
    

    console.log(searchItems);

    let searchMatches = searchRes.filter(searchItem => {
        console.log(searchItem);
        const searchRegex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return searchItem.itemName.match(searchRegex);
    });
    if (searchText.length === 0) {
        searchMatches = [];
        searchMatchList.innerHTML = '';
    }
    
    outputSearchHtml(searchMatches);
};


const outputSearchHtml = searchMatches => {
    if (searchMatches.length > 0) {
        const html = searchMatches.map(searchMatch => `
        <div class ="card">
            <h4>${searchMatch.name}</h4>
        </div>
        `).join('');

        searchMatchList.innerHTML = html;
    }
}

module.exports = handleSQLite;
```

It is just very frustrating as I know how I want to do everything else but just cannot get past this hurdle.

Oh then I guess here is my `index.html` as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>



    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Storage Lookup</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="btns">
            <button class="sel-btn search">Search</button>
            <button class="sel-btn insert">Insert</button>
            <button class="sel-btn remove ">Remove</button>
        </div>

        <div class="search-sec hidden">
            <p>by</p>
            <div class="search-btns">
                <button class="search-sec-btn">Box</button>
                <button class="search-sec-btn">Item</button>
            </div>
            <div class="search-input-go">
                <div class="search-input-cont">
                    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Item Name">
                    <input type="image" src="/img/search.png" name='searchbtn' class="search-btn"/>
                </div>
                <div id="match-list"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="insert-sec hidden">

            <div class="insert-btns">
                <input type="text" class="insert-input" id='input-insert-box' placeholder="Box Number">
                <input type="text" class="insert-input" id='insert-input-item' placeholder="Item Name">
            </div>
            <div class="insert-btn-con">
                <button class="insert-sec-btn">Insert</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The difference

If I understood you correctly, what you are trying to do is impossible.
You can't access db from browser directly.

Unless nodejs and browser-side javascript "speaking" one language, they are very different things. NodeJS is designed to be server-side, so it uses server specific things like Operating system related utils, filesystem.

So running sqlite in browser is like running jquery on server -- there is no such a thing like DOM in NodeJS like there is no such a thing like `fs` in browser.

## How then?

In the common case the client code and the server code don't know much about each other. They deal with each other via API like classical client-server apps.

Simple example abstractly looks like:

Browser: asks server for /api/users route via `GET` request
Server: *does the job like going to DB, extracts data*
Server: return data to Browser, mostly likely in JSON
Browser displays data

and etc.